# Template isn't resolving type to correct overload

Tags: c++, templates, boost, visual-c++-2010, boost-variant

This is on Visual Studio 2010, utilizing Boost v1.48.0. I'm trying to get a boost::variant with some structs and shared pointers to structs to match the right members of a boost::static_visitor, without success...

For my problem, let's establish this premise, as an example:

```
struct t_type_A { int key; foo value; };
struct t_type_B { int key; bar value; };
struct t_type_C { int key; baz value; };
struct t_type_D { int key; qux value; };

bool operator<(const t_type_A &, const t_type_A &);
bool operator<(const t_type_B &, const t_type_B &);
bool operator<(const t_type_C &, const t_type_C &);
bool operator<(const t_type_D &, const t_type_D &);

bool operator==(const t_type_A &, const t_type_A &);
bool operator==(const t_type_B &, const t_type_B &);
bool operator==(const t_type_C &, const t_type_C &);
bool operator==(const t_type_D &, const t_type_D &);

typedef std::shared_ptr<t_type_C> t_shared_C;
typedef std::shared_ptr<t_type_D> t_shared_D;

typedef boost::variant<t_type_A, t_type_B, t_shared_C, t_shared_D> t_variant;
```

I have a visitor as follows:

```
class variant_less : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    result_type operator()(const T &left, const T &right) const
    {
            return left.value < right.value || (left.value == right.value && left.key < right.key);
    }

    template<typename T, typename U>
    result_type operator()(const T &left, const U &right) const
    {
            return left.key < right.key;
    }

    template<typename T>
    result_type operator()(const std::shared_ptr<T> &left, const std::shared_ptr<T> &right) const
    {
            return left->value < right->value || (left->value == right->value && left->key < right->key);
    }

    template<typename T, typename U>
    result_type operator()(const std::shared_ptr<T> &left, const std::shared_ptr<U> &right) const
    {
            return left->key < right->key;
    }
};
```

In practice, when I apply the visitor to my variants, I get a compiler errors as:

EDIT: I had to look at the error message again. I mistranslated that to this example, it's not complaining about 'value' but'key'. The error is fixed below.

error C2039: 'key' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>'

The compiler is resolving the comparison between two t_shared_C or two t_shared_D as:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
result_type operator()(const T &left, const U &right) const
```

being the best fit. This is obviously not what I desire. Alternately, I've tried the following, based on my shaky knowledge of SFINAE:

```
class variant_less : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    result_type operator()(const T &left, const T &right) const
    {
            return left.value < right.value || (left.value == right.value && left.key < right.key);
    }

    template<typename T, typename U>
    result_type operator()(const T &left, const U &right) const
    {
            return left.key < right.key;
    }

    template<typename T>
    result_type operator()(const T &left, const T &right) const
    {
            return left->value < right->value || (left->value == right->value && left->key < right->key);
    }

    template<typename T, typename U>
    result_type operator()(const T &left, const U &right) const
    {
            return left->key < right->key;
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to give up and write overloads for every combination.

EDIT: Here is how it's getting invoked:

```
typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
    t_variant_vector,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<variant_extractor<1234>, variant_less>
      , boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<variant_extractor<5678>, variant_less>
      // arbitrarily more indexes go here
    >
> t_variant_multi_index;
```

The vector is a sorted vector of variants, sorted by key. The indexes are so indexed by the presence of variants with particular 'key' values. variant_extractor finds and pulls the variant with the matching key. As a brief on what mult_index is then doing, the result of the 'key extractor', a variant, is then used as a parameter to the 'comparison predicate', variant_less, for sorting that index.

Comment: Your description seems off.   You say it's resolving to `result_type operator()(const T &left, const U &right) const`, but that one doesn't use `value` at all, so it appears to be selecting a different overload.

Comment: This doesn't look like a `boost::static_visitor`. Those require `operator()` with single parameters.

Comment: @dyp Boost static_visitor does support binary operators.

Comment: Please show us how you're trying to invoke those `operator()`.

Comment: @Dave S I see what you mean.

Comment: @MatthewReddington Hmmm I'm currently looking at [the static visitor concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#variant.concepts.static-visitor) and [the `static_visitor` class template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/static_visitor.html) but I can't find where that's allowed/supported.

Comment: &dyp look at apply_visitor. The static_visitor concept only requires result_type, and says nothing of the operator overloads.

Comment: It seems you're right, the concept is `MultiVisitor`, not `StaticVisitor`, but it's not very well documented as far as I can see.

Comment: @Dave S, I corrected the error message and added a comment. Crossed the streams in translation...

Comment: &dyp being v1.48.0, there is no multi_visitor concept that exists in later versions, but this does work.

Comment: The problem seems to be an instantiation where the first argument to `operator()` is not a shared pointer, but the second one is (i.e. mixed arguments). I'm not yet sure *why* it is instantiated, though.

Comment: The instantiation probably happens since it's a run-time decision which function to call. So you have to support mixed arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to template instantiation. When compiling, T and shared_ptr are both considered as a certain type, and compiler doesn't differentiate a plain type or a share_ptr type, so the compiler will find the first matched template function definition to instantiate the function, that's how your error happens.

You can do something similar as std traits: provide two tag types:

```
struct plain_type_tag{};
struct shareptr_type_tag{};
```

Then change your functions to:

```
 template<typename T, typename U>
    result_type operator()(const T &left, const U &right, plain_type_tag) const
    {
            return left.key < right.key;
    }

    template<typename T>
    result_type operator()(const std::shared_ptr<T> &left, const std::shared_ptr<T> &right, shareptr_type_tag) const
    {
            return left->value < right->value || (left->value == right->value && left->key < right->key);
    }
```

For you reference:

1. [An Introduction to "Iterator Traits"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36530/An-Introduction-to-Iterator-Traits).  It deals with similar problems.
2. [Function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template): explain the function template instantiation

Comment: Before I mark your response as the answer, can you provide an edit to explain how it works? I've got *some* template-fu, but this is a bit magical to me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `apply_visitor` must instantiate the `operator()` of the MultiVisitor for all combinations of the variants' contents: It is a run-time decision which function will be called (since the type of the content of the variant is only known at run-time).

Therefore, the MultiVisitor has to support all combinations of arguments. This includes combinations where one argument is a `shared_ptr` but the other one is not.

Here's a solution that simply unpacks all `shared_ptr`s. This also removes the code duplication.

```
class variant_less : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
private:
    template<typename T>
    result_type impl(const T &left, const T &right) const
    {
        return    left.value < right.value
               || (left.value == right.value && left.key < right.key);
    }

    template<typename T, typename U>
    result_type impl(const T &left, const U &right) const
    {
            return left.key < right.key;
    }

    template<typename T>
    static T const& unpack(T const& p)
    {
        return p;
    }
    template<typename T>
    static T const& unpack(std::shared_ptr<T> const& p)
    {
        return *p;
    }

public:
    template<typename T, typename U>
    result_type operator()(const T& left, const U& right) const
    {
        return impl(unpack(left), unpack(right));
    }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eec11b15f87fa02b)

Comment: Certainly a novel solution. I like it.